Angular Form with Checkboxes that Display Sections
Apologies on what might be an easy question but as a Product Manager trying to write Angular I'm hitting my head on the wall.
What I'm trying to create is an Angular form that has conditional sections. There's an initial checkbox: Should entry information be collected?
Based on this being checked it should open up the next section: Entry Categories
Within Entry Categories there are four options: Apple, Banana, Orange, Kiwi
If ANY of the four options in Entry Categories are selected it should open up the next section: Entry Details AND the entry details tied to that category should show the options.
All Entry Details are the same they have a checkbox for: Organic, GMO, Lego and an input with placeholder: Fruit Name
So if Apple is selected in Entry Categories it should open up Entry Details and display the following checkboxes: Organic, GMO, Lego; and a Fruit Name input.
I've been able to put a conditional from the first checkbox to the Entry Categories from here is where it gets dicey. My original attempt was a compilation of using formControlNames and every checkbox correlating with ngModel. It was also hyper complex. So then I made some massive changes to pull from an array in the ts file.
I'm running into the following issues:

With all the options in the ts file how can I grab the last option and make it into an input?
I have Contact as default being checked, but it's not actually being marked as checked, is there a way?
Is there a way to keep the Entry Details at the top section and push the results into a separate section?

My original entry html and ts files:
entry.component.html
 <div fxlayout="row" fxLayoutalign="start center" class="padded-bottom">
  <mat-checkbox id="requireEntryInformation" formControlName="requireEntryInformation" [(ngModel)]="showEntryProduct">Should entry information be collected?
  </mat-checkbox>
 </div>
 <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutalign="start center" id="entryProductCategorySection" *ngIf="showEntryProduct">
  <h2>Entry Categories</h2>
   <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="stretch">
     <div fxFlex="50" fxFlexOffset="10" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="baseline">
      <mat-checkbox id="apple_category" [(ngModel)]="showApple">Apple</mat-checkbox>
      <mat-checkbox id="orange_category">Orange</mat-checkbox>
     </div>
     <div fxFlex="50" fxFlexOffset="10" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="baseline">
      <mat-checkbox id="kiwi_category">Kiwi</mat-checkbox>
      <mat-checkbox id="banana_category">Banana</mat-checkbox>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start center" id="entryDetailSection" *ngIf="showEntryDetailSection">
   <h2>Entry Details</h2>
    <div fxLayout="row" *ngIf="showApple">
     <h3>Apple</h3>
     <mat-checkbox>Organic</mat-checkbox>
     <mat-checkbox>GMO</mat-checkbox>
     <mat-checkbox>Lego</mat-checkbox>
    </div>
  </div>

entry.component.ts
showEntryProduct: boolean;
showApple: boolean;
defineFormGroup = () => {
 this.initializeDefaultFormValues();
 this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  requireEntryInformation: [this.defaultFormValues['requireEntryInformation'], Validators.required]
 });
}

That failed a lot so I built out:
StackBlitz Example
I don't know how to handle an input field in the entry array.
  entries = [
    {
      name: 'Apple',
      options: ['Organic', 'GMO', 'Lego'],
      checked: false,
      field_name: 'String'
    },
    {
      name: 'Banana',
      options: ['Organic', 'GMO', 'Lego'],
      checked: false,
    },
    {
      name: 'Kiwi',
      options: ['Organic', 'GMO', 'Lego'],
      checked: false,
    },
    {
      name: 'Contact',
      options: ['Email Required?', 'Address Required?'],
      checked: true,
    },
  ];

In my results as soon as I click on the Apple it immediately loads the Entry Details when I want that section to be completely after Kiwi.
Actual Results

You should start with the "data" you want to "store", not with the .html
Some like
<div fxlayout="row" fxLayoutalign="start center">
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="showEntryProduct"
    >Should entry information be collected?
  </mat-checkbox>
</div>
<div *ngIf="showEntryProduct">
  <div>
    <h2>Entry Category</h2>
    <div *ngFor="let entry of entries">
      <div>
        <mat-checkbox
          [checked]="entry.checked"
          (change)="unselectRest(entry)"
          >{{ entry.name }}</mat-checkbox
        >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let entry of entries">
      <div *ngIf="entry.checked">
        <div>
          <h2>Preferred {{ entry.name }}</h2>
          <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let option of entry.options">{{
            option
          }}</mat-checkbox>
        </div>
        <input mat-input [(ngModel)]="fruitName"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

using in .ts
  //declare also a variable fruitName
  fruitName:string="";

  unselectRest(entry:any){
      this.entries.forEach(x=>{
        x.checked=x==entry
      })
  }

Show the data (I make "exclusive" the checkbox), but you can not know what are the option selected
if the checked are "exclusive" we can change a bit the "entries" array adding a property: selected
entries = [
    {
      ...
      selected:-1,
    },
    {
      ...
      selected:-1,
    },
    ....
]

then we can change also the mat-check related to options
      <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let option of entry.options;let i=index" 
         [checked]="entry.selected==i"
         (change)="entry.selected=$event.checked?i:-1">
         {{option}}
      </mat-checkbox>

Now we have all we need in "entriesArray. e.g. in submit you can use some like
submit()
{
    //find the entry checked
    const entrie=this.entries.find(x=>x.checked)

    //create an object "on fly" with the values
    const result=entrie?{name:entrie.name,
                         option:entrie.selected>=0?entrie.options[entrie.selected]:
                                                   '',
                         fruitName:this.fruitName}:null
    alert(JSON.stringify(result))
      
}

a stackblitz
NOTE: There'r anothers ways to do, I only show a way using the event (change) of the mat-checkbox and [checked] property. If you're not using material, you can use some similar using ngModel. It's possible alse do some similar using reactive forms (but the philosophy change a bit)
NOTE2: remember: always think first in the data we can get, after think about the .html

This is incredibly close to the desire affect so I appreciate the answer. Probably poorly worded in my description is the need to allow for multiple entry names ie: Apple, Banana, Kiwi to be shown collectively. Can probably address with removing the change. The other issue is the input tied to EACH entry category ie Apple Name, Banana Name, etc. But this pushes me in a better direction. Thank you!
